# how do I combine objects in order to display all at the same time as JSON?

Tags: c#

In the code below, check the following line:

```
//here I need to put the object "nd" into a "bucket" so that I can finish the loop and then return EVERYTHING together.
```

My question is, how do I combine objects to return as JSON? The reason why I need to "combine" is because of the loop which assigns values to specific properties of this class. Once each class has been done getting property values, I need to return everything as JSON.

```
namespace X
{
    public class NotificationsController : ApiController
    {
        public List<NotificationTreeNode> getNotifications(int id)
        {
            var bo = new HomeBO();
            var list = bo.GetNotificationsForUser(id);
            var notificationTreeNodes = (from GBLNotifications n in list
                                        where n.NotificationCount != 0
                                        select new NotificationTreeNode(n)).ToList();

            foreach (var notificationTreeNode in notificationTreeNodes)
            {
                Node nd = new Node();
                nd.notificationType = notificationTreeNode.NotificationNode.NotificationType;

                var notificationList = bo.GetNotificationsForUser(id, notificationTreeNode.NotificationNode.NotificationTypeId).Cast<GBLNotifications>().ToList();
                List<string> notificationDescriptions = new List<string>();

                foreach (var item in notificationList)
                {
                    notificationDescriptions.Add(item.NotificationDescription);
                }

                nd.notifications = notificationDescriptions;

                //here I need to put the object "nd" into a "bucket" so that I can finish the loop and then return EVERYTHING together.
            }

            return bucket;
        }
    }

    public class Node
    {
        public string notificationType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public List<string> notifications
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add each item to a list as you're iterating through the source collection:

```
public List<Node> getNotifications(int id)
{
    var bucket = new List<Node>(notificationTreeNodes.Count);

    foreach (var notificationTreeNode in notificationTreeNodes)
    {
        Node nd = new Node();
        ...

        bucket.Add(nd);
    }

    return bucket;
}
```